# Integral of a real function giving a complex result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Why, when I compute the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\alpha}dx\int_{0}^{\alpha}dy\frac{\ln|x-y|}{\sqrt{(\alpha-x)(\alpha-y)}}
$$
for $\alpha>0$, by executing the following:

```
Assuming[α > 0, 
 FullSimplify[
  Integrate[
   Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)], {x, 
    0, α}, {y, 0, α}]]]
```

do I get the complex-valued answer:

```
4 α (-3 + I π + Log[4] + Log[α])
```

The integrand is real-valued, so surely the integral must be too?! I believe the answer should be $4\alpha(\ln(\alpha)+2\ln(2)-3)$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Using the simplification to remove `Abs` that others have posted, and changing variables with `x,y` --> `alf-x,alf-y` converts this to something quite tame from the point of view of symbolic integration: `In[186]:= 
2*Integrate[Log[x - y]/Sqrt[x*y], {x, 0, alf}, {y, 0, x}, 
   Assumptions -> alf > 0] // Simplify

Out[186]= 4 alf (-3 + Log[4] + Log[alf])`

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_, y_, α_] = Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)];
```

The singularity at x == y is a difficulty for Integrate.

```
Plot3D[f[x, y, 3], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

Since  `f[x, y, α] == f[y, x, α] // Simplify`  is True

```
Assuming[α > 0, 
   2*Integrate[
     Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)], {x, 
        0, α}, {y, x, α}]]//Timing


(* {0.765, 4 α (-3 + Log[4] + Log[α])}   *)
```

Comment: The usage of symmetry (by hand) shortens the execution to 7.09958 s from 137.817 s.

Comment: @user64494   0.765  seconds on version 8.0

Comment: My comp is not strong.

Comment: Mine is i7-4790  not the newest one. Think difference in versions.

Comment: Interestingly, using the lower triangular region (bounds `{y,0,x}`) gives the erroneous complex result.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

With v13.0.1 the integral doesn't evaluate fully

```
f1[x_, y_] = Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)];

int1 = Assuming[α > 0,
  Integrate[f1[x, y], {x, 0, α}, {y, 0, α}]]
```

[image]

However, since the argument of `Abs` is real, then

```
f2[x_, y_] = 
  Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)] /. Abs[t_] :> Sqrt[t^2];

int2 = Assuming[α > 0,
  Integrate[f2[x, y], {x, 0, α}, {y, 0, α}]]

(* 4 α (-3 + Log[4] + Log[α]) *)
```

Or,

```
f3[x_, y_] = 
  Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)] /. Abs :> RealAbs;

int3 = Assuming[α > 0,
  Integrate[f2[x, y], {x, 0, α}, {y, 0, α}]]

(* 4 α (-3 + Log[4] + Log[α]) *)
```

Comment: Looks as a regression in 13.1  comparing with 13.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, I sometimes throw in seemingly extraneous assumptions:

```
Integrate[
 Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)], {x, 
  0, α}, {y, 0, α}, 
 Assumptions -> α > x > 0 && α > y > 0]

(*  4 α (-3 + Log[4] + Log[α])  *)
```

This is twice as fast (and risky):

```
Integrate[Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(α - x) (α - y)],
 {x, 0, α}, {y, 0, α},
 Assumptions -> α > x > 0 && α > y > 0, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
```

The difference between the OP's code and my first code is that while `α > 0` implies `α` is real, because inequalities imply the terms are real in Mathematica, `{x, 0, α}` does not imply `x` is real.  The integration may take a complex path between two numbers that happen to be real, and `Integrate` tries to deal with that. (`GenerateConditions -> False` turns off some of the checking, and therefore it shortens the computation.)  Now, I don't know the internal workings well enough to know what I've said is actually why the computation works (e.g., whether any component of the computation ever uses the assumption that `x` is real under `α > x > 0` and does not assume `x` is real under the OP's assumption).
This is not a hard-and-fast rule, either: consider `Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, I, 1}]` with and without the `I`, and apparently, sometimes `x` treated to be real.
I do know that this trick has worked for me before, and this is how I explain it to myself so that I might remember to use the trick when I get an unexpected complex result.  It could be that some component of the calculation fails to add the condition that `x` as real, but adding thus, `Assumptions -> α > 0 && {x, y} \[Element] Reals`, fixes the problem (this works, too, but I like the more stringent version, just in case).
All I know, as I just said, is that this works sometimes and is worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

In 13.0.0 on Windows 10

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(\[Alpha] - x) (\[Alpha] - y)], {x, 
0, \[Alpha]}, {y, 0, \[Alpha]}, Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]]
```

> `4 \[Alpha] (-3 + Log[4] + Log[\[Alpha]])`

It takes a few minutes. The same result without `FullSimplify`.

Comment: It should be noticed the integral under consideration exists for $\alpha<0$ too. The command `Integrate[
 Log[RealAbs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(\[Alpha] - x) (\[Alpha] - y)], {x, 
  0, \[Alpha]}, {y, 0, \[Alpha]}, Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > -Infinity,
  GenerateConditions -> True]` results in $$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -4 \alpha  (\log (-4 \alpha )-3) & \alpha <0 \\
 4 \alpha  (\log (\alpha )-3+\log (4)) & \alpha >0 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array} .$$

Comment: I use version 12.0. Is this therefore a bug that has since been fixed?

Comment: @Chris: As you see. I prefer `Assumptions` over `Assuming` and `RealAbs` over `Abs`.

Comment: but why should that make any difference to the answer?

Comment: @Chris: In 13.0.0 `Assuming[\[Alpha] > 0, 
 Integrate[
  Log[Abs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(\[Alpha] - x) (\[Alpha] - y)], {x, 
   0, \[Alpha]}, {y, 0, \[Alpha]}]]` produces `4 \[Alpha] (-3 + Log[4] + Log[\[Alpha]])` too.

Comment: `Assuming[\[Alpha] > -Infinity, 
 Integrate[
  Log[RealAbs[x - y]]/Sqrt[(\[Alpha] - x) (\[Alpha] - y)], {x, 
   0, \[Alpha]}, {y, 0, \[Alpha]}]]`  results in `\[Piecewise] -4 \[Alpha] (-3+Log[-4 \[Alpha]]) \[Alpha]<0
4 \[Alpha] (-3+Log[4]+Log[\[Alpha]]) \[Alpha]>0
0 True

`